# How do I get the list of container instances given an EC2 instance ID in the Python AWS boto API

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, boto3

I've been scouring the EC2 api in Python's boto3 client (http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html). Given an EC2 instance ID, I want to be able to find all the container instances that run on that EC2 instance belonging to a particular ECS cluster ID. I can't seem to find any API call that does this. How can I get this information?

I want this information because given an EC2 instance ID I want to know all the containers and all the tasks running on those containers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do this with the ECS API. E.g.

```
import boto3

CLUSTER = 'YOUR_CLUSTER_ID'
EC2 = 'YOUR_EC2_ID'

ecs = boto3.client('ecs')

ci_list_response = ecs.list_container_instances(
    cluster=CLUSTER
)

# Describe those ARNs
ci_descriptions_response = ecs.describe_container_instances(
    cluster=CLUSTER,
    containerInstances=ci_list_response['containerInstanceArns']
)

# Look for a container instance with the given EC2 instance ID
# Then for want of something better to do, print all the details
for ci in ci_descriptions_response['containerInstances']:
    if ci['ec2InstanceId'] == EC2:
        print(ci)
```

---

Edit: It occurred to me that you might be more interested in what tasks are running on that instance, which you can also get.

```
import boto3

CLUSTER = 'YOUR_CLUSTER_ID'
EC2 = 'YOUR_EC2_ID'

ecs = boto3.client('ecs')

ci_list_response = ecs.list_container_instances(
    cluster=CLUSTER
)

# Describe those ARNs
ci_descriptions_response = ecs.describe_container_instances(
    cluster=CLUSTER,
    containerInstances=ci_list_response['containerInstanceArns']
)

# Look for a container instance with the given EC2 instance ID
# Then for want of something better to do, print all the details
for ci in ci_descriptions_response['containerInstances']:
    if ci['ec2InstanceId'] == EC2:

        # List tasks on this container instance
        t_list_response = ecs.list_tasks(
            cluster=CLUSTER,
            containerInstance=ci['containerInstanceArn']
        )

        # Describe tasks
        t_descriptions_response = ecs.describe_tasks(
            cluster=CLUSTER,
            tasks=t_list_response['taskArns']
        )

        print(t_descriptions_response)
```

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to get to it using the EC2 api, didn't know I had to use ECS!